# How can I remove padding on a div column for only mobile?

Tags: html, css

I have this div column in a content row:

```
<div class="col-md-4 no-gutter" style="float: right;">
<div class="well">
<p>blah blah blah (content) </p>
</div>
</div>
```

[image: Screenshot of problem area]

I am using a CMS (Cascade Server) with Bootstrap 2.

This worked to remove the gutter padding...

```
[class*='col-'].no-gutter {
   padding-right:0;
   padding-left:0;
}
```

...but upon looking at it in desktop view, I need some padding for screens over 992px wide so that the text doesn't run up to the div column. I tried adding the following but I think my sytax is wrong and I don't know how to fix it. Can someone help me?

```
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) and [class*='col-'].no-gutter {
   padding-right:0;
   padding-left:15;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Quantastical is correct about the formatting... another minor issue, you're also missing px on the end of the padding-left. With 0 you don't need it but with other values you'll need px, em, % specified

```
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
   [class*='col-'].no-gutter {
      padding-right:0;
      padding-left:15px;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You `@media` syntax is wrong. It needs to surround your CSS declarations like so:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
   [class*='col-'].no-gutter {
      padding-right: 0;
      padding-left: 15px;
   }
}
```

See the [W3 documentation on Media Queries](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) for more information on how to use them.

*Edit: Add units to `padding-left` per [Kyle Larson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35784413/1028949) No sense promoting poor code.*